# Image vortex for a point vortex inside a circle

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

Need help with the specific question related to the circle theorem.

Let $z$ be a complex number.
Show that the image of a line vortex of strength $2 \pi \kappa$ located at $z = b$ inside the circle $|z| = a $ can be written as:

$w_2(z) = i \kappa \log(z − a^2/b)$

I know that the line vortex inside the circle has the potential $w_1(z) = i \kappa  \log(z − b)$ but it has a singularity at $z=b$ which is inside the circle so I cant apply the circle theorem.

I've also tried applying the circle theorem to $w_2(z)$ instead in hopes to find $w_1(z)$ but with little success

Any help would be great.

Comment: Hi, could you provide a reference for this "circle theorem"? it seems there are many different theorems that share this generic name.

Comment: Hey sure no worries- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milne-Thomson_circle_theorem